# Permanently update a website's HTML code on button click w/ HTML/PHP, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website that I use to display my art projects, and I'd like to create a seperate hidden HTML page in which, through a UI form, I can add a line of HTML code that updates an image to my website's main directory.

The website is: josiegee.com

Can the website's source code be actually updated permanently through the click of a button with only HTML/PHP?

I've figured out how to change the code temporarily, but not permanently. If I wanted to achieve this, could someone point me in a general direction so I know where to start? Thank you!

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting

Comment: You would need to have admin rights to do that.

Comment: Sorry I'm very unfamiliar with this website, I just needed somewhere to ask much more experienced web developers a quick question.

Answer (score 0):

Still, to answer your question, unless you use some really clever trickery, it's not really possible with conventional tools for multitude of reasons, mainly security based.

If you are trying to achieve dynamic changes to your website, then you would want to use REST or Ajax requests.